# Read python array from bash in windows?

Tags: python, windows, bash

I have an array in python:

```
list = ['text1','text2','text3',...]
```

I need to read that array from bash in Windows.
So I have two questions:

```
1. How to keep python array(.pky, .txt) to be able to read from bash?
2. How to read that array from bash in Windows?
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to do.J ust save list content in a text file and after you can access from bash.

```
my_list = ['text1','text2','text3',...]
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in my_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

For Example :

```
my_list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
with open ('test.txt','w') as f :
    for item in my_list:
        f.write("%s\n"% item)
```

*test.txt* file will be generated at the location of the script, you can also define a path for that text file by doing like this :

```
with open (r'PATH\test.txt','w') as f :
```